# Move existing file with a makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have in my makefile the following code:

```
CONTIKI_PROJECT = blank
UPNP = ..
RT = $(UPNP)/../uJ/BUILDENV/RT/
APPL = $(UPNP)/../uJ/Applications/

CCVT    ?= $(UPNP)/../classCvt/classCvt
TOBIN   ?= $(UPNP)/../classCvt/tobinfile
CMD = $(TOBIN) -c $(CCVT)

upload:
    CLASSPATH=$(RT)/real:$(RT)fake:$(RT)/fake/uj javac $(RT)/real/java/lang/*.java
    CLASSPATH=$(RT)/real:$(RT)/fake:$(RT)/fake/uj javac $(APPL)/UJ*.java 
    CLASSPATH=$(RT)/real:$(RT)/fake:$(RT)/fake/uj \
        javac $(APPL)/UJ*.java $(APPL)/$(CLASS).java
    find $(APPL)/ -iname "$(CLASS).class" >> temp_files
    $(CMD) $(APPL)/$(CLASS).class >$(CLASS).raw_ujc
```

The ".raw_ujc" file appears in the directory of the makefile, as expected, and is a simple text file.
The tobinfile is a .c file that does printf and its output gets put into .raw_ujc.
However, similarly it produces a binary file while doing the printf (by doing   fwrite(&v,sizeof(v),1,rawf) with v being the byte and rawf being the file with a specific name).
This produces the binary file in the $(APPL) folder.
I'd like to move this file to the folder of the makefile, where the .raw_ujc file also resides.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the answer you're looking for as simple as:

```
$(CMD) $(APPL)/$(CLASS).class >$(CLASS).raw_ujc
-mv $(APPL)/rawf .
```

This moves the file `rawf` from the `$(APPL)` directory to the current directory after the `$(CMD)` has executed.  The `-` prefix ignores errors in the move (if the `rawf` file is not there for example) and might not be something you want.

Comment: Thank you. I am always confused with makefiles and lack a handy oversight of commands to use with it. Any good clue for tutorials?

Comment: @Sven  The commands within the recipe parts of a makefile are just shell commands, and are interpreted by the shell.  The make manual https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc-Writing-Recipes-in-Rules has more details.